# Hide cmd window from Clarion

Tags: cmd, clarion

Is there a way to hide a cmd window in Clarion 8?

I run xcopy to copy files defined in fields an application so it looks something like this:

```
Run('Xcopy '&Clip(Loc:Pathfrom)&' '&loc:Pathto')
```

i.e. `Run(' C:\Temp\Temp.tps c:\Bakup\')`.

Maybe there is a cmd or Clarion command not to show the black window but only do the copying?

Answer (score 1):

I understand why you don't want to use the builtin COPY command as you should need to find every single file (and possibly folder too) under that folder you want to copy. If I were you I'll use the proper tools to do it: Windows API and hide the window.

```
PROGRAM

SW_HIDE             EQUATE(0) 
SW_SHOW             EQUATE(5) 

  MAP
 MODULE('SHELL')
    ShellExecute(hWnd,|
                *CSTRING Operation,|
                *CSTRING PathAndFileName,|
                *CSTRING CommandLineParameters,|
                *CSTRING DefaultDirectory,|
                 LONG ShowCommandCode),|
                   hInstance,|
                     PASCAL,RAW,NAME('ShellExecuteA')
 END
END

LOC:OPN  CSTRING(50)
LOC:NSTR CSTRING(100
LOC:CMD  CSTRING(255)
LOC:DD   CSTRING(255)
 CODE

LOC:OPN  = 'open'
LOC:NSTR = 'C:\Temp\Temp.tps c:\Bakup\'
LOC:DD   = 'C:\Temp'
LOC:Cmd  = 'XCOPY'
ShellExecute(0{PROP:Handle},LOC:OPN,LOC:CMD,LOC:NSTR,LOC:DD,SW_HIDE)
```

This code has not been tested.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using the [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) API function with the `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` flag is another way to do this?

You should be able to locate some examples in Clarion code around the place. A good starting point is the `CreateProcessCaptureOutput` method of `CML_System_IO_CaptureStdOutput.clw` found in the ClarionMagLibrary:

https://github.com/devroadmaps/ClarionMagLibrary/tree/master/libsrc

Tweak that as needed?

Answer (score 0):

No. Using the Clarion `RUN()` function with a console application like `xcopy.exe`, it isn't possible to hide the command line interface window using the documented options.

Example Clarion program:

```
PROGRAM

  MAP
  END

pathFrom cstring('C:\Temp\Temp.tps') !You could use STRING instead of CSTRING, but then must use CLIP(pathFrom) below
pathTo   cstring('c:\Backup\')
  CODE
  !You will see a black cmd.exe console window open to run ththe following CLI command
  Run('xcopy ' & pathFrom & ' ' & pathTo, true) !second parameter of true means to wait for the program being "run" to complete.
```

However, One way to workaround this is to use a non-console application to do the work, or to simply run the console app with the command line interface hidden. I have done the latter with [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com). Just as Clarion offers a `Run()` function, so does AutoIT, but with the additional ability to hide the window.

AutoIT script (runhidden.au3 compiled as runhidden.exe):

```
Opt("TrayIconHide",1) ;This hides AutoIT's default systray icon from appearing
dim $command = $CmdLine[1] & ' ' & $CmdLine[2] & ' ' & $CmdLine[3] & ' ' & $CmdLine[4]
Run ( $command,"",@SW_HIDE)
```

Example Clarion program which uses the compiled AutoIT script above:

```
PROGRAM

  MAP
  END

pathFrom cstring('C:\Temp\Temp.tps')
pathTo   cstring('c:\Backup\')
  CODE
  !You won't see a black cmd.exe console window opened by the following CLI command:
  Run('runhidden.exe xcopy '& pathFrom & ' ' & pathTo, true)
```

You need not use AutoIT for the above technique, but AutoIT is free and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is some reason that you prefer to use the command line copy/xcopy command, why not just use Clarion's built in Copy function to copy the file?

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).