# with a geocoding api is compulsory to open the browser

Tags: background-process, google-geocoding-api, silent, clarion

I'm trying to get Lat & Lng via Google Geocoding API. It works, but... it is compulsory to open a browser? (send the Https...comand), there is no way to send the comand and get the 2 values (numbers) back in the background of a Clarion app that I'm currently developing? via a DOS command?

Comment: Please edit your question and give some context to help us answer. What's that app? In which language is it written, which tools does it use..?

Comment: If you use a RUN command with IEXPLORE.EXE as the command line you can use an API to run the ShellExecute command and hide that window.

Comment: To declare ShellExecute take a look at my response on this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25851041/hide-cmd-window-from-clarion

Answer (score 0):

What version of Clarion are you using?

This can be done in version 10 with

```
HttpWebRequestToFile
```

or

```
HttpWebRequest
```

Older versions of Clarion is easy if you use Capesoft's Nettalk. http://www.capesoft.com/docs/NetTalk/nettalk.htm